# Trace of Matrix Exponential closed form expression

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

I would like to compute the $\mathbf{tr}(e^A)$ where $A$ is some square matrix with entries that have only values of either $0$ or $1$, and $\mathbf{tr}$ is the trace operator.  Are there closed form expressions for this or some way to compute it easily without having to compute the actual matrix exponential for every element in A?

I have gotten this far:
$$ \mathbf{tr}(e^A) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!} \mathbf{tr}(A^k) $$ due to the property that
$$ \mathbf{tr}(A+B) = \mathbf{tr}(A) + \mathbf{tr}(B) $$
but not sure how to go further and perhaps get a simpler expression?  I would like some expression form of this because I am going to use this as a constraint in an optimization problem... otherwise I wouldn't worry about the computational cost of computing all the elements of $e^A$.

Comment: Is your matrix diagonalizable, that would make life simpler

Comment: I don't know if I can assume that unfortunately ..., I will look into figuring out if it is diagonalizable, but if so, how does this make life simpler?

Comment: Well, $\mathbf{tr}(A^k)=\sum_i\lambda_i^k$. Can you make use of that?

Comment: If your matrix is diagonalizable then it can be written as $A = P^{-1}DP$ where D is diagonal, then it is easy to calculate traces of powers of such matrix since $\operatorname{Tr}((P^{-1}DP)^k) = \operatorname{Tr}(P^{-1}D^k P) = \operatorname{Tr}(D^k) = \sum_i \lambda^k_i$

Comment: Right, good point to both Triatticus and @amd, I guess I need to look to see if my matrix will always be diagonalizable.  Wonder if people have any ideas if I cannot ensure this for A?

Comment: It doesn’t need to be diagonalizable, just similar to an upper-triangular matrix. You can save yourself some work by using the fact that the trace is preserved by conjugation, as in Mnifldz’ answer, below.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a general form for this expression, but it relies on the fact that every square matrix has a **Jordan canonical form.**  That is, for every $A$ there is invertible matrix $Q$ and some block diagonal $J$ with 1's on the super-diagonal such that $A = Q^{-1}JQ$.  Notice now that $A^k = (Q^{-1}JQ)^k = Q^{-1}J^kQ$ and so your sum for the matrix exponential reduces to

$$
\exp(A) \;\; =\;\; Q^{-1} \left ( \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}J^k \right ) Q \;\; =\;\; Q^{-1} \exp(J) Q.
$$

Now, given the fact that $Tr(ABC) = Tr(BCA) = Tr(CAB)$ we have that $Tr(\exp(A)) = Tr(\exp(J))$. Because you're only computing the trace, you only need to worry about the diagonal values in the Jordan block matrix $J$.  Therefore

$$
Tr(\exp(A)) \;\; =\;\; \sum_{\lambda \in \Lambda(A)} m_\lambda e^\lambda
$$

where $\Lambda(A)$ is the set of distinct generalized eigenvalues of $A$, and $m_\lambda$ is the multiplicity corresponding to $\lambda \in \Lambda(A)$.