# Does there exist a real matrix $A$ for the given matrix $e^A$?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, matrix-exponential

Does there exist a matrix $A \in \Bbb R^{2 \times 2}$ such that the following holds?

$$e^A = \begin{pmatrix}-4 && 0 \\ 0 && -1\end{pmatrix}$$

---

I know that for a Jordan block

$$J=\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda&1&0&0&\dots\\
0&\lambda&1&0&\dots\\
0&0&\lambda&1&\dots\\
0&0&0&\lambda&\dots\\
&&\vdots&&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$e^{Jt}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&\frac{t}{1!}&\frac{t^2}{2!}&\frac{t^3}{3!}&\dots\\
0&1&\frac{t}{1!}&\frac{t^2}{2!}&\dots\\
0&0&1&\frac{t}{1!}&\dots\\
0&0&0&1&\dots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots
\end{pmatrix}$$

And using the Jordan normal form of a matrix $M:$ $M=TJT^{-1}$ it holds:

$$e^{Mt}=Te^{Jt}T^{-1}$$

I think that such a matrix $A$ does not exist because the eigenvalues are negative and $\ln (-4)$, $\ln(-1)$ is undefined but I don't know how properly prove that such a matrix doesn't exist.

Comment: No: [look at the trace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821508/trace-of-matrix-exponential-closed-form-expression).

Comment: The fact that $A$ has non-real eigenvalues (i.e. that $e^A$ has negative eigenvalues) is not enough on its own.  For instance, we find that
$$
\exp\pmatrix{0&-\pi\\ \pi & 0} = \pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-1}
$$

Comment: [A wiki source for T's trace identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_determinant_of_the_matrix_exponential)

Comment: @T.Bongers the trace satisfies $e^{\operatorname{tr}(A)} = \det(e^A) = 4$; how does that help?

Comment: Some theory on the subject: http://www.m-hikari.com/ija/ija-password-2008/ija-password1-4-2008/morsyIJA1-4-2008.pdf In particular Theorem 3 seconds Omnom's answer.

Answer (score 4):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $e^{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $e^A$.  So, since $e^A$ has eigenvalues $-1,-4$, $A$ has one eigenvalue satisfying $e^{\lambda_1} = -1$ and another satisfying $e^{\lambda_2} = -4$.

However, the strictly complex eigenvalues of any real matrix must come in conjugate pairs.  That is, if $\lambda$ is a non-real eigenvalue of $A$, then the conjugate $\overline{\lambda}$ must also be an eigenvalue.  This tells us that $A$ cannot be real, since there is no complex $\lambda$ satisfying $\exp(\lambda) = -1$ and $\exp(\bar \lambda) = -4$.