# Calculate trace of matrix with complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, matrix-exponential

I'm trying to calculate  $\text{tr}(\exp(A)) $  for matrix $A$, and I found several topics, but not sure if I've get it all right. So I wonder if this is a correct way of doing this.

This is matrix $A$,
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & -1 & 1 \\
    -1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
Following the answer in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1821508/trace-of-matrix-exponential-closed-form-expression), I calculated the eigenvalues, two of which are complex numbers,

$$\ \lambda_1 = 1.52 , \lambda_2= -0.76+0.85 i , \lambda_3= -0.76-0.85 i \\
\    tr(e^A) = e^{1.52} + e^{-0.76+0.85 i} + e^{-0.76-0.85 i} \\
\
$$

As suggested [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859276/complex-numbers-as-exponents), I've written the following for the complex parts

$$\ 
\    e^{-0.76+0.85 i} + e^{-0.76-0.85 i}= e^{-0.76}.e^{0.85i}+e^{-0.76}.e^{-0.85i}\\ =e^{-0.76}(\cos0.85 + i \sin 0.85+\cos-0.85+i\sin-0.85) = e^{-0.76}.2\cos(0.85) 
\
$$

So finally we have, $\text{tr}(\exp(A)) = e^{1.52}+e^{-0.76}.2\cos(0.85)  $

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to [check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eig(%7B%7B0,-1,1%7D,%7B-1,0,1%7D,%7B1,1,0%7D%7D)) calculations, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixExp(%7B%7B0,-1,1%7D,%7B-1,0,1%7D,%7B1,1,0%7D%7D)) is usually a nice place to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Sorry my bad.. I'll check it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a computational error somewhere. Since $A$ is a real symmetric matrix, its eigenvalues must be real. The eigenvalues of $A$ are all $-2$ and $1$ (twice). So, the eigenvalues of $e^A$ are $e^{-2}$ and $e$ (again, twice), and therefore$$\operatorname{tr}(e^A)=e^{-2}+2e.$$

Comment: Terribly sorry, I'd written a wrong A. I corrected it.

Comment: And I have adapted my answer to the new version of the qquestion.

Comment: Thank you so much, I get it now. Bad mistake.. There was no need to get into complex numbers any way.. Thanks

Comment: Could you please explain why the eigenvalues of $e^A$ are $e$ raised to the eigenvalues of $A$? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Consider $v$ an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, take a look at $e^Av$, expand the exponential and simplify. You get $e^\lambda v$ at the end.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is a diagonalizable matrix. Hence,
$$
A=Q\Lambda Q^{\mathrm T},
$$
where $Q$ is orthogonal and $\Lambda$ is diagonal with the eigenvalues of $A$ on the diagonal.
We have that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{tr}(\exp(A))
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\operatorname{tr}(A^k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\operatorname{tr}(Q\Lambda^k Q^{\mathrm T})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda^k Q^{\mathrm T}Q)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda^k)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{2+(-2)^k}{k!}\\
&=2e+\frac1{e^{2}}
\end{align*}
using the fact that $\operatorname{tr}(ABC)=\operatorname{tr}(BCA)$ and the fact that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$, $1$ and $-2$.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Note that we may choose $Q$ to be orthogonal because $A$ is symmetric. This doesn't hold in general. On the other hand, diagonalisation is generally done with $Q^{-1}$ rather than $Q^T$, so it doesn't really matter that much. However, $A$ being symmetric immediately implies it is actually diagonalizable, without us having to check eigenvalues and eigenspaces.

Comment: It was indeed helpful, Many thanks